# CHDB cache error when trying to store array

Tags: php, caching, pecl

I'm trying to use CHDB (hash table caching) for PHP (http://pecl.php.net/package/chdb).

I end up with this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error
>   generating 'd.chdb': Cannot allocate memory' in
>   /var/www/b/site/test.php:18 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/b/site/test.php(18): chdb_create('d.chdb', Array) #1 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/site/b/test.php on line 18

Does anyone know where this error comes from? Is it from the PHP framework itself or from somewhere else?

I manually installed CHDB in PHP on Fedora 11.

My code is very straightforward:

```
   $data = array('key1' => "val1");
   chdb_create("d.chdb", $data);
```

Any helpful tips welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmer of chdb answered my question and the problem is that cmph library used by chdb does not allow hashing of arrays with size one. I used one entry just to test...

Simple as that :-).

Obviously the error message is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the CHDB source in detail, but it's possible that "unable to allocate memory" message actually translates as "unable to open file".

I've just had a quick browse through the source code (you can find it at https://github.com/lcastelli/chdb), and that exception appears to come from [here](https://github.com/lcastelli/chdb/blob/master/php_chdb.c#L120), but I've no idea where it's actually trying to write its files. Never tried using it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I do not have any idea where it's trying to write its files either. I was thinking it was the RAM or something, but I'm probably misstaken...